# VBScript error: Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed. Error 800a0e7a

Tags: windows, oracle, vbscript, 32bit-64bit, adodb

I'm getting this error

> Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed. Code:
>   800a0e7a Source: ADODB.Connection" when I try to run my VBScript

It's trying to connect to an Oracle database, here is the connection string:

```
Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;
Data Source=Data;
User Id=Username;
Password=password;
```

I have Oracle Client 32 installed, my machine is a 64 bit system. I've tried re-register Oracle OLEDB provider dll with:
 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32 \bin\OraOLEDB12.dll

I've tried opening it with a 32 bit driver and still keep getting that error. Any ideas?

Comment: Try to launch the script running `wscript.exe` from `C:\Windows\System32` and `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.

Answer (score 0):

By default your script will run in 64-bit mode. As your Oracle client is 32-bit you must run your script also 32-bit mode.

Try `c:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe {your_script.vbs}` to run it. Otherwise you would have to install the 64-bit version of Oracle Client.